C# align methods by dot when wrapped
I'm trying to set up vs code for developing .net applications and now having some troubles with align. When developing in Rider i can easily set up align by dot with Line break before dot in multi-line chained method call and Align multiline chained method calls.
How can i do this using VS Code?
// current state
var result = myService.DoSomething()
.DoAnotherThing()
.DoMore();

//desired result
var result = myService.DoSomething()
                      .DoAnotherThing()
                      .DoMore();

I've already tried setting up editorconfig, read the msdn code-style guide

The method chain indenting seems to be resharper/rider specific, and not standard editorconfig. There may be extensions for VSCode that does it, but I don't have anything top of my head.

Wrap & Align seems to be available in vscode as a refactoring QuickAction. But not an automatic one via editorconfig
